# Plot axis not meeting at origin

Tags: r, plot

Consider the following vector:

```
  q1 <- c(1000000.0,  908364.8,  876009.1,  847892.8,  824808.3,  805416.2,  785266.2, 770997.1,  753908.6,  744599.9,  706777.6,  674659.9,  634654.4,  601440.4, 568259.7,  535361.3,  493679.9,  465526.5,  429766.6,  395244.7,  361483.2, 332136.6, 308574.5, 285500.6, 262166.2 ,237989.0 , 210766.1,  188578.1, 166762.3 , 140399.8  ,114865.5)
```

Here is the plot:

```
 dev.new(width=10, height=5)
 par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
 plot(q1, type = "l", lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = "green", xaxt = 'n', xlim = c(0,30), bty = "l")
 x.ticks = seq(from = 0, to = 30, by = 5)
 axis(1, at = x.ticks+1,  labels=paste("Year", x.ticks, sep=" "))
```

[image]

For some reason, my x-axis and y-axis are not meeting at (0,0)!  I tried fixing this by using `par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')`, but it doesn't do the trick in this case?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't specify `ylim` and your `xlim` should start at 1 not 0.

Comment: Well, xlim starts at 1, not zero (note the "x.ticks + 1" in `axis()`). I tried specifying ylim, doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: I just tried the exact same thing you suggested, and it doesn't work, I am sorry.. I have added `ylim = c(0, max(q1,  na.rm = TRUE))` to the `plot` with no success

Comment: I have plotted this graph before, and didn't have this problem, now suddenly this is happening...

Comment: Then there is something else going on in your R session that you haven't told us. Because simply changing it to `xlim = c(1,30),ylim = c(0,max(q1))` works.

Comment: I am not sure what's going on either.. It use to behave just fine until now.. Any guess?

Comment: Well, then there's definitely something else going on that you haven't told us. Because the code you showed should _never_ have worked as you wanted it to, and it would be wrong if it had. Always test in a fresh, clean R session.

Comment: I closed all my R sessions, and open a new script, ran the code above along with your suggestion, still the same problem.

Comment: :shrug: Works just fine for me. (Also, note that you really _do_ need to set `xlim = c(1,...)`. Just adding 1 in `axis` doesn't change how the plotting window is set up.)

Comment: @Thanks.. Indeed, I need to set the lower bound to 1 for xlim. I thought the "+1" would have taken care of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not specify ylim, R will fit the plot area to the data, not extend the plot to the origin.  This will fix it:

```
plot(q1, type = "l", lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = "green", xaxt = 'n', 
     xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0, max(q1,  na.rm = TRUE)), bty = "l")
```

I wrote the ylim to look for the maximum in q1.  You can change it to a fixed value.

Here is the full code I ran to make it work:

```
q1 <- c(1000000.0,  908364.8,  876009.1,  847892.8,  824808.3,  805416.2,  
        785266.2, 770997.1,  753908.6,  744599.9,  706777.6,  674659.9,  
        634654.4,  601440.4, 568259.7,  535361.3,  493679.9,  465526.5,  
        429766.6,  395244.7,  361483.2, 332136.6, 308574.5, 285500.6, 
        262166.2 ,237989.0 , 210766.1,  188578.1, 166762.3 , 140399.8  ,114865.5)

dev.new(width=10, height=5)
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
plot(q1, type = "l", lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = "green", 
     xaxt = 'n', xlim = c(1,30), ylim = c(0, max(q1)), bty = "l")
x.ticks = seq(from = 0, to = 30, by = 5)
axis(1, at = x.ticks + 1,  labels=paste("Year", x.ticks, sep=" "))
```

Comment: If you set xlim = c(1, 30) as suggested above, Year 0 will meet exactly with 0e+00, given you keep xaxs and yaxs equal to 'i'.  A better solution would be to drop the + 1 from the at argument in the axis statement.